# How to get access to "/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/" using Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android, whatsapp, android-11, storage-access-framework

I working on an application and I want to access the "/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses" to fetch data in statuses folder for my applications.

Comment: There is no problem description or question.

Comment: I want to access this directory in android 11 using SAF

Comment: Please put that in your post. Not in a comment. Write a decent post. Also then tell what the problem is using SAF as it is easy doable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the Storage Access Framework? If you have access to the directories you are describing, you should be able to use the Java "File" library to perform all of your file/directory access tasks.

Comment: No I can't directly access this directory in android 11

Comment: You need to root your device then - you don't have access as a user

Answer (score 0):

Its android 11 problem
To access that folder you need All Files Access Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
    android:maxSdkVersion='28'/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> //---This
```

Make sure to ask that permission.

Answer (score -2):

/storage/emulated/0/Movies/.thumbnails/.database_uuid